# Proving that Emb($D^m,N$) is homotopy equivalent to $V_m(TN)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, h-principle

I am reading online lecture notes by John Francis on h-principle. I want to prove that

Emb($D^m,N$) is homotopy equivalent to $V_m(TN)$ where $V_m(TN)$ is stiefel bundle of the tangent bundle on $N$.

So to prove this we first construct a map from $F:$Emb($D^m,N$) $\to V_m(TN)$ given by $F(f)=(f(0),df(0)(T_0(D^m)))$.

Now we construct the reverse map say $G$. So suppose we have a point of $V_m(TN) $ this is equivalent to the data a point of $N$ say $x$ and a map $i:\mathbb{R}^m \to T_xN$. Now we first put a Riemannian metric on $N$. Now scale the map $i$ such that the image of disc around the origin lies in the normal neighbourhood. Now we have a map $\lambda i:\mathbb{R}^m \to T_xN$ such that $\lambda i(D_m) \subset U$ where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ such that $exp : T_xN \to N$ when restricted to $U$ is a diffeomorphism. Now the composite map $exp \circ \lambda i$ gives an embedding. This is the reverse map.

Now I want to show that this map is the homotopy inverse of $F$. For that we have to show that if $f \in$ Emb($D^m,N$) then $exp \circ df_0$ isotopic to $f$. I am unable to prove this statement. If anyone can give any hints it would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: What you said is not true. You have to show that there is a *canonical isotopy* - one that works for all $f$ - not just that these two things are isotopic for each $f$. (The latter would just prove they have the same $\pi_0$.) Anyway, try scaling until you can fit the embedding into a chart and then just pointwise interpolate between your old disc and the new disc. (That is, try to reduce this to proving that $T_0 \Bbb R^n$ and $\text{Emb}((D^n,0),(\Bbb R^n,0))$ are naturally homotopy equivalent.)

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for pointing out the mistake and also for the suggestion. I am having a problem with how to interpolate between old disc and new disc via embeddings I don't think a linear interpolation will work and I am unable to think of anything else

Comment: If $f$ is your first embedding, consider the family $f_t(x) = f(tx)/t$, defined for $t \in (0,1]$; it admits a continuous extension to $t=0$, and the value at $t=0$ is precisely the linear embedding with the same derivative.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks a lot